# How to change the message of an alert dialog when one of its button clicked?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` with "Tell me more" and "OK" buttons, I want to change its message when user clicks on 'Tell me more' button and hide this button. How can I do this?

I have this code currently:

```java
new AlertDialog
    .Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Initial message")
    .setNeutralButton("Tell me more", (dialog, which) -> {
        // change dialog's message to "Detailed message".
        // hide this "Tell me more" button
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
    .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `setMessage` method you would have to create a custom layout for your dialog, with the buttons in the layout.
You would then set the click listeners to the buttons in your layout and update the text and the button visibility in the layout.

```
val binding = MyDialogBinding.inflate(/* todo */)
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    binding.button.isVisible = false
    binding.textView.text = /* new text here */
}
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(binding.root).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use AlertDialog, use Dialog.
or in your case, you can show other or new AlertDialog on button cliked

example in kotlin

```
fun showDialogWithButton() {
val dialog = Dialog(this)
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
dialog.setCancelable(true)

val tvMess = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_body_dialog) as TextView
val btnOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok) as Button
var more = false
tvMess.text = "Initial message"
btnTell.text = "Tell me more"
btnOk.setOnClickListener {
if(!more)
{
        tvMess.text = "some thing more"
        btnOk.text = "OK"}
more = true
}else{
dialog.dismiss()
}

}
dialog.show()
```

}